# Safely process user content in Django template language

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm making a blog app in Django, where the users can write their own blog post.

I have the worry that the User could introduce malicious code in the database while writing a blog post.

For example, by writing javascript code in the blog post body:

```js
alert("malicious code here, ahh!)
```

So there is any way to process the content of the user by parsing the value of the content, or something like that?

Comment: This is a very broad subject that can't be fully answered in a Stack Overflow post, but you might start by removing all HTML tags but a few allowed ones using something like [bleach](https://pypi.org/project/bleach/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, I'll check for bleach

Comment: take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escape